# function toLowerCase broken

Tags: javascript, html, function

Having some issues with toLowerCase() function. I need to edit text in a text area. My basic colour change function gets a user to input a colour into the text area. It uses if statements and was working fine before I added the toLowerCase().

```
function colourChange() {
   var the_colour = document.forms["formTwo"]["textBox"].value;
   the_colour = the_colour.toLowerCase();

   if(the_colour == "red") {
      document.formOne.textArea.style.color ="red";
   } else if (the_colour == "blue") {
      document.formOne.textArea.style.color ="blue";
   } else if (the_colour == "green") {
      document.formOne.textArea.style.color ="green";
   } else if (the_colour == "yellow") {
      document.formOne.textArea.style.color ="yellow";
   } else {
      alert("Please enter red, blue green or yellow")
   }
```

My HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js">
</script>
<form name="formOne">
<textarea rows="5" cols="45" id="textArea" name="textArea">
</textarea>
</form>

<form name="formTwo">
Colour:<input type="text" name="textBox" value="red, blue, green or yellow.">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: By "broken" what does your code do? Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: When does `colourChange` get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the error console I saw it was a syntax error. The form tag should not be given a name attribute.

Try this:

```
function colourChange( theForm ) 
{
  var color =
  {
    red : "red", 
    blue  : "blue",
    green : "green",
    yellow : "yellow"

  }[ theForm["textBox"].value.toLowerCase() ];

  color ?  document.getElementById( 'formOne').textArea.style.color = color 
        :  alert("Please enter red, blue, green or yellow");

  return false;  
}

</script>
```

Above there is a ternary statement and then it uses an associative lookup on an object.
The HTML

```
<form id="formOne">
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textAreav" name="textArea" style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.5em'>
TEXT
</textarea>
</form>

<form>
Colour:<input type="text" name="textBox" value="red, blue, green or yellow.">
<button onclick="return colourChange( this.form )">Change Colour</button> </body>
</form>

</html>
```

Lastly there are 2 form tags inside the code please remove one.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

**The HTML**:

```
<form>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="45" name="textArea"></textarea>
</form>

<form>
    Colour:<input type="text" name="textBox" value="red, blue, green or yellow.">
</form>
```

As you can see, I've not given any name to the forms. Giving names to forms is unnecessary. Just name your fields. That's good enough.

**The JavaScript:**

```
function colorChange() {
    var color = textBox.value.toLowerCase();

    switch (color) {
    case "red":
    case "blue":
    case "green":
    case "yellow":
        textArea.style.color = color;
        break;
    default:
        alert("Please enter either red, blue, green or yellow.");
    }
}
```

Named fields can be directly accessed in JavaScript using the name itself.